# Update a column by adding 1 to that column whos primary key is not the minimum

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I am basically just trying to add 1 to a column in every row of the table whos primary key is not the minimum. I placed the code below. Can someone help me out with the logic?

```
    UPDATE MyTable
SET LineNumber = (case when TableID != min(TableID) then LineNumber + 1)
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  mt
SET     LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
FROM    MyTable mt
WHERE   TableID <> 
        (
        select  min(TableID) 
        from    MyTable
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this?

```
  update MyTable
    set LineNumber = LineNumber + 1
  where
    TableID > (SELECT MIN(TableID ) FROM MyTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
UPDATE MyTable SET LineNumber = LineNumber +1 WHERE TableID != MIN(TableID) FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in a where as in [Andomar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13381371/119477) answer but if you really wanted to use a case statement you could do this

```
UPDATE
  MyTable
SET LineNumber = 

  CASE WHEN TableID = (SELECT MIN(TableID) MinID FROM MyTable) 
       THEN LineNumber
       ELSE LineNumber+ 1
  END
FROM
  MyTable;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1909f/12)